# python flatten nested json dictionary with panda.json_normalize

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to obtain a flattened structure using pandas from the following json example.

```
{
    "not_interesting_1": 100,
    "not_interesting_2": false,
    "_not_interesting_nested_1": {
        "ni_count": 200,
        "successful": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 999,
            "_not_interesting_thing": "foo_bar"
        },
        "some_value": 4.76,
        "hits": [{
            "_type": "record",
            "_source": {
                "name": "aunt bob",
                "age": "76",
                "capacity": "low",
                "motivation": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "_type": "record",
            "_source": {
                "name": "uncle mary",
                "age": "68",
                "capacity": "medium",
                "motivation": "7"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Using the following code

```
with open(r'C:\Users\nunya\desktop\test.json') as f:
    r = json.load(f)

result = panda.json_normalize(r, record_path=['hits', 'hits'])
print(result)
```

I can get the following result:

```
    _type _source.name _source.age _source.capacity _source.motivation
0  record     aunt bob          76              low                  2
1  record   uncle mary          68           medium                  7
```

Which is pretty close to what I'm wanting.. but I **REALLY** want to get this:

```
   name             age     capacity    motivation
0  aunt bob         76      low         2
1  uncle mary       68      medium      7
```

Is there a way to start flattening at the dict that I'm missing?

I've tried this:

```
result = panda.json_normalize(r, record_path=['hits', 'hits','_source'])
```

and this:

```
result = panda.json_normalize(r, record_path=['hits', 'hits',['_source']])
```

Based on some examples I've seen, but they both end like this:

```
path ['_source']. Must be list or null.
```

or this:

```
path _source. Must be list or null.
```

How do I tell pandas to navigate into the dict and then start flattening ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are asking is nonstandard so we need to get a bit creative:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_string = """{
    "not_interesting_1": 100,
    "not_interesting_2": false,
    "_not_interesting_nested_1": {
        "ni_count": 200,
        "successful": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 999,
            "_not_interesting_thing": "foo_bar"
        },
        "some_value": 4.76,
        "hits": [{
            "_type": "record",
            "_source": {
                "name": "aunt bob",
                "age": "76",
                "capacity": "low",
                "motivation": "2"
            }
        },
        {
            "_type": "record",
            "_source": {
                "name": "uncle mary",
                "age": "68",
                "capacity": "medium",
                "motivation": "7"
            }
        }]
    }
}"""

r = json.loads(json_string)

result = pd.json_normalize(pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(r).loc['hits']['hits'])._source)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
         name age capacity motivation
0    aunt bob  76      low          2
1  uncle mary  68   medium          7
```

Comment: This works BEAUTIFULLY.. I'm curious, what part is "nonstandard" ?? That I want to take this approach with Pandas.. or, the JSON structure itself??  Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) only handles nested dictionaries (that's the "standard" configuration) therefore normalising a list inside a nested dictionary requires a bit more work.

Comment: Maybe you can contribute to the code base to improve it 

I really appreciate your help !!